# How to send html file to GrammarApi

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api

I am trying to apply spell checking feature on the resume templates. I am using https://www.grammar.com/grammar_api.php Api. I am able to analyze the string but I want to send an HTML file.
Please suggest how can I do that.

Code to send a string.

```
app.post('/', function(req,res){

    text  = req.body.sentence;
    const url = "https://www.stands4.com/services/v2/grammar.php?uid=8816&tokenid=" "&text=" + text + "&format=json";
     
    https.get(url, function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    response.on("data",function(data){
        const grammar = JSON.parse(data);
        const result = grammar.matches[0].message;
        res.send("The grammar api result is" + result);
        
    });
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean to send the text of the HTML file, or the entire HTML file contents? Can't imagine the latter being helpful to you.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Actually, this API does not have a method to Analyze the whole HTML file directly. I am looking for a way to send user data to this API as the user type on template and spell check it and will replace it correct spelling like Grammarly does. But this API only able to analyze a single sentence only at a time.